# In React after calling setState, are there hard and fast rules for avoiding asynch errors when accessing/changing state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and this is my first time handling asynchronous operations.  Currently I am building a simple calculator and have run into some minor issues after using setState and then immediately trying to access the state.  It's been easy to work around the issues because my app is pretty simple.  However, I haven't been able to find definitive rules for how long it takes after calling setState to be certain that state has actually been updated.  Does it require a certain amount of time?  Is it dependent on the structure of my code?  Also, is it appropriate to use setTimeout after setState in order to give state time to update?  If anyone could give me some insight into when React will update the state and save me the guesswork, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post relevant code?

Comment: Could you show your code, please? That would simplify the process of giving suggestions.

Comment: Well, currently my code doesn't have any issues.  Initially, if a user pressed '=' on my calculator immediately after having pushed an operator button (+, -, * or /), it would remove the operator from the array in state, and then calculate the expression in the array directly from the state.  This didn't work, as the state didn't update the operator removal before it tried to calculate the expression.  I'm learning to make as little changes and references to the state as possible to avoid errors.  However I'm wondering if there are general rules to know for certain when state will be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it require a certain amount of time?

No specific amount.

> Is it dependent on the structure of my code?

In a general way, but that's not really the question. :-)

> Also, is it appropriate to use setTimeout after setState in order to give state time to update?

No.

> In React after calling setState, are there hard and fast rules for avoiding asynch errors when accessing/changing state?

Yes. They're covered in the documentation, particularly [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). They are (at minimum):

1. The only way to know state has finished changing is to use `componentDidUpdate` or the completion callback you can provide to `setState` (the second argument):

   ```
   this.setState(newState, () => {
       // `this.state` has the updated state
   });
   ```
2. If you're changing state based on existing state, you must use the form of `setState` that accepts a function as its first argument and calls it with the up-to-date state for you to change.
3. (Not async specific.) **Never** directly modify the state object or any object it refers to.

So for example: Suppose you have an array (`items`) and you need to push an entry into it if it's not already there:

```
// WRONG, breaks Rule #3
if (!this.state.items.includes(newItem)) {
    this.state.items.push(newItem);
}

// WRONG, breaks Rule #2
if (!this.state.items.includes(newItem)) {
    this.setState({items: [...items, newItem]});
}

// WRONG, breaks Rule #1
this.setState({items: [...items, newItem]});
doSomethingWith(this.state.items);
```

Instead:

```
this.setState(
    ({items}) => {
        if (!items.includes(newItem)) {
            return {items: [...items, newItem]};
        }
    },
    () => {
        doSomnethingWith(this.state.items);
    }
);
```

But note that using the completion callback (the second function above) is usually an anti-pattern; really the only thing a component should do when state updates is re-render, and React will call `render` for you.

But this answer is **not** a substitute for reading through [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). :-)

Comment: This was incredibly helpful.  Thank you!  I guess it's time to read the documentation... ^_^

Answer (score 2):

`setState` takes a callback as second parameter:

```
this.setState({
  foo: 'bar'
}, () => {
  // This code will be executed after setState has been processed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the state after `setState()` you can do that in the callback function for the same to verify the actual state is being updated.
Like this:

`this.setSate ({
     test : 'Hello Word'
}, () => {
    console.log('this.state', this.state)
})`

Whenever the state is changed, it compares the DOM and virtual DOM to find out differences, and renders them on the actual DOM.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: What does this answer provide that the two previous ones do not?

Comment: All answer explains the same with different example perspective. Also when I had posted the answer. and scroll two above someone already posted the answer. I'm just trying to help you with above example

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your components don't care about the timing of a `setState` update.

Most likely what you are looking for is the `setState` call that is based on the previous state...

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
          // I almost always just spread the state onto a new object.
          ...prevState,
          // Then you'll want to add your updated properties below. This overrides the old state that you set above
          someProp: newVal
    };
});
```

From there, again, your components shouldn't care about when React actually performs the update! (As with all things there are exceptions of course)